# How to sort both data member arrays of a class in code shown

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a simple C++ code written to understand sort function usage on user defined class data types to sort data members of a class.

But this only sorts array of variable b in the class. Because, the earlier sorted array of variable a, is also disturbed whiel sorting b.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

class Entry
{
public:
int a, b;
};

bool compare1(Entry e1, Entry e2)
{

if (e1. a > e2. a) return false;
return true;

}

bool compare2( Entry e1,  Entry e2)
{

if (e1. b > e2. b) return false;
return true;

}

int main()
{
int i;



vector<Entry> array(4);
array[0]. a =5 , array[0]. b =8 ;
array[1]. a =10 , array[1]. b =4 ;
array[2]. a =3 , array[2]. b =2 ;
array[3]. a =1 , array[3]. b =12 ;



sort(array.begin(), array.end(), compare1);
sort(array.begin(), array.end(), compare2);



cout << "sorted:" << endl;
for (i = 0; i< 4; i++)
cout << array[i]. a << " " << array[i].b << endl;

}
```

The output I get is as follows:

```
sorted:
3 2
10 4
5 8
1 12
```

How to sort both data member arrays - a,b?

Comment: Here is a hint: sort once, compare twice. One of your fields is more important than the other.

Comment: You don't sort the members of the type, but the whole objects in the container according to the comparison function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you want your elements to be sorted:

1. Sort as pairs, keyed on `a`: (1,12), (3,2), (5,8), (10,4)
2. Sort as pairs, keyed on `b`: (3,2), (10,4), ...
3. Sort as pairs lexicographically: same as sorting on `a`, since there are no repeated values for `a`.

In case (1) you use `compare1`, in case (2) you use `compare2`. (For case (3) you would have to write another predicate, or just use `std::pair<int,int>`.)

Case 4: If you want the values of `a` and `b` sorted *separately* and destroy the pairing, then you need to put the values into *separate* vectors of ints and sort those individually:

```
std::vector<int> avals(array.size()), bvals(array.size());

for (size_t i = 0; i != array.size(); ++i)
{
  avals[i] = array[i].a;
  bvals[i] = array[i].b;
}

std::sort(avals.begin(), avals.end());
std::sort(bvals.begin(), bvals.end());
```

There is no way around this. A container of `Entry` objects can only move elements around as a whole.

Comment: I think case 4 is what he wants, but it's hard to be sure

Comment: @MD: Quite. I'm baffled why the OP has this intermediate class which clearly doesn't reflect what she needs or wants to express.

Comment: Yes, I want the both members to be sorted independently. No pair wise sorting or such thing. I thought about getting the array members into another buffer and then sorting that. But wanted to be sure if there is no possible way in present class itself.

Comment: @goldenmean: I think having this class doesn't make any sense if you want the elements arranged individually. Just scrap the `Entry` class and maintain two separate vectors of ints.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing what `sort` does. It does not hort the *members* that you use in the comparison function, but rather the whole objects. In your case that means that the because you initialized one object with value pair `(5,8)`, there will always be an element in the vector that is `(5,8)`.

Sorting the array by the first member means that it move to the second to last position (`5` being the second to last biggest first element), and sorting by the second element will move the object to, well in this case also the second to last position, but that will only *move* the object in the container, it will always be `(5,8)`.

Comment: @Georg: Thanks... I am too tired to pay attention.

Answer (score 0):

If you want both to impact the comparison, include both in the check (i.e. `compare`) function. Else, it's either one or the other. If you need to have different "views", you need a smarter container (such as boost::multi_index)